# React: Within a container how to render a component on to another one without rerender others?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My question seems a bit vague, first let me explain what I want to do with an image:

[You can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHwOZ.png)

I have a container component, lets say Stars. Inside that component I have two others are being rendered: Actors and Actresses. As you can see there are links to Movies and TV Shows, which are also two components. What I want is when I click to Movies it will render on to Actors without rerender Actresses. Same thing goes for Actresses.

At that point, I have some basic knowledge for React and React Router. I tried my luck with Routes and Switches but I can't get to work it. Here is my question, is this possible? If yes, what can/should I use? States or any other method I don't know yet (like Redux)?

Or my strategy is not a good one? ie, this is not possible without rerendering the container component?

My React version: 16.0.0-alpha.12

My React Router version: 4.1.1

Edit: I changed the question a little bit. In the original one I asked the  question with the phrase "without changing URL". But, this is not my main point. I just want to swap components without rerendering the other ones in the container.

Comment: If you want to render different components inside a container component without changing URL, there is no point of trying to do that with react router. Instead,  use internal state of container component.

Comment: Actually I might have asked the question wrong ( I can change it). I don't want to rerender the second component (my main purpose) and I thought if I change the URL I have to rerender it. I can work on states, I know the basics. I just want to learn the right or preferable way here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be handled through state in the container, however assuming you want to do that through URLs, React-Router comes with an option for nested routes.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/04-nested-routes

if you create a routes for actors and a route for actress, this might be possible to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think there is no more nested Routes in React 4. After two days I started to think about not having two components, but instead having one and using states in it as all you said.

Comment: I haven't upgraded to React-Router 4 yet so I didn't know :) It doesn't play nice with a bunch of other libraries

Comment: React Router has changed so much in a couple of months and I dived in nowadays. Some old advises and answers and some new, so much struggle :)

Comment: Accepting this answer for the container and states part. As I coded I realized that it is very easy (and also not impossible :) ) to do what I wanted.